# Using pure non-I/O Haskell functions to split a list on new lines

Tags: haskell

```
type UserRating = (String, Int)
data Film = Film
    { title :: String
    , director :: String
    , year :: Int
    , userRatings :: [UserRating]
    } deriving ( Show )

testDatabase :: [Film]

testDatabase = [Film "Blade Runner" "Ridley Scott" 1982 [("Amy",6), ("Bill",9), ("Ian",7), ("Kevin",9), ("Emma",4), ("Sam",5), ("Megan",4)],
                Film "The Fly" "David Cronenberg" 1986 [("Megan",4), ("Fred",7), ("Chris",5), ("Ian",0), ("Amy",5)]]
averageRating ::[UserRating] -> Float
averageRating rating =   fromIntegral (sum [b|(a,b) <- rating])/fromIntegral (length rating)

showAllFilms :: [Film] -> String
showAllFilms [] = []
showAllFilms (x:xs) = printf "%s %s d %3.1f\n" (title x) (director x) (year x) (averageRating(userRatings x)) ++ showAllFilms xs
```

I need to split the list Film on new lines without using any I/O function, is this possible? Most solutions use putStr but that's an I/O function. I'm new to Haskell, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: By "split" do you mean "join"?  You can just use `unlines $ map show testDatabase`.  If you're wanting to print it to the screen then you'll _have_ to use IO

Comment: Values should appear like: Blade Runner Ridley Scott 1982 2.2 etc on a new line. Tried "\n" but it gets appended at the end

Comment: I'm still trying to understand what your question is.  Are you wanting to read these values from strings to the `Film` type or convert your existing `Film`s in `testDatabase` to `String`s then output them to the screen?  Please try to be as specific and descriptive as you can.

Comment: Another way to put it would be, given a function `solveProblem` what would be your desired input and the return value for that function?

Comment: I want to call a function from the ghci> that will give me values: Blade Runner Ridley Scott 1982 2.2 and The Fly David Cronenberg 1986 4.9 on separate lines. The function should output a String and not a Film type. Been able to convert them to a String type but my problem is putting each on separate lines. "\n" gets appended at the end when I use printf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you want to see

```
> showAllFilms testDatabase
Blade Runner Ridley Scott 1982 5.0
The Fly David Cronenberg 1986 4.3
```

(I just made up the average ratings)

But instead you're seeing

```
> showAllFilms testDatabase
"Blade Runner Ridley Scott 1982 5.0\nThe Fly David Cronenberg 1986 4.3\n
```

This is because when you evaluate a function in GHCi, it *prints* the output automatically.  If you were to type

```
> testDatabase !! 0
```

You would see a nicely formatted, non-string output of the first `Film`, but what's happening under the hood is that GHCi is really running

```
print $ testDatabase !! 0
```

Which is equivalent to

```
putStrLn . show $ testDatabase !! 0
```

So if you want the `\n` to render as new lines and you want the quotation marks to be absent on your output, you *have* to print it.  You can test this by

```
> "test\n"
"test\n"
> show "test\n"
"\"test\\n\""
> putStrLn $ show "test\n"
"test\n"
> putStrLn "test\n"
test

>
```

An alternative would be not to derive the `Show` instance and instead do the following:

```
instance Show Film where
    show (Film t d y rs) = printf "%s %s d %3.1f" t d y (averageRating rs)
    showList films s = unlines (map show films) ++ s
```

Then when in GHCi,

```
> testDatabase
Blade Runner Ridley Scott 1982 5.0
The Fly David Cronenberg 1986 4.3
```

You get pretty printed output.

Comment: Been trying to wrap my mind round the alternative though I'm not sure my lecturer expects me to do this as I don't recall him mentioning "instance". But what does showList do? Basically are you saying the only to achieve the new line feature is with putStrLn?

Comment: @user3388396 `showList` is a member of the `Show` typeclass.  It has a default implementation that you're used to seeing when printing a list, but can be overwritten in cases like `show ([] :: [Char])`, where you want the list to be treated like a string instead of a list (`String = [Char]`).  Basically, it just gives you a way to customize printing a list for your data type.  The extra `s` parameter there is just to make it type check (don't worry about it for now).

Comment: @user3388396 As far as I know, the only way to acheive the new line feature is with IO when in GHCi.  You have to remember that GHCi is a REPL written in Haskell, it reads in a line (an `IO` action) and outputs a result (another `IO` action), everything you do is technically in the `IO` monad.

Comment: I just want to thank you again. Clearly I missed the lecture when instance was taught.

Comment: @user3388396 Glad it's been sorted out.  If my answer helped you, please accept it so that others will know at a glance that this is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly your question, you want to map `show` on each element of the list and get a single string where each element has its own line.
You might want to have a look at `unlines:: [String] -> String`, from [Data.List](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Data-List.html#v%3aunlines), which does exactly what you want to do.
So, let's say you start from a simpler `showFilm :: Film -> String` instead, which doesn't add trailing newlines:

```
showAllFilms l = unlines $ map showFilm l
```

Comment: why not just use `unlines` instead of `intercalate "\n"`?

Comment: Because I totally forgot about it's existence. Thanks for pointing it out, fixed :)

Comment: isn't putStr an I/O function? i am not meant to use any I/O function to achieve this.

Comment: Yes it is, I added it as an example in order to print out immediately the result. I removed it however, since it seems to bother you: the result as a simple string you meant to obtain is simply what you get from applying unlines to the result of the map.

Comment: I used this showAllFilms l = unlines $ map showFilm l and I still had "\n" appended at the end of each String

Comment: That's why I used putStr before.